# Click buttons like Add jar and Add External Jar disabled in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Please let me know how to Enable this two buttons in Eclipse oxygen. Thanks in advance. I think I have disabled it mistakenly.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 9 (supported since Oxygen.1a) a project has a ***Modulepath*** and a ***Classpath***. The **buttons are deactivated until one** of the two paths to which the JAR should be added **is selected**.

Comment: More details on the difference between both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321602/in-eclipse-what-is-the-difference-between-modulepath-and-classpath/50324391