# Can not import JUnit with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

## Evnironments

- Mac OS High Serial 10.13.6
- Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Hi,
I am having trouble create Junit Test Case with Eclipse.
I've google this error, but all the posts tell me that you have to add.
As shown below I had.

The error is `The import org cannnot be resloved`

Somebody know what are the possibilities of my problems ?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1605sy6t612mp2d/Screenshot%202018-10-04%2019.32.05.png?dl=0]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you expand that JUnit 5 node in the Package Explorer, do you see jars there? Can you find the Test class you're trying to import in one of them (and show it to us)?

Comment: Thank you just edited the post

Comment: Are you able to add JUnit5 to the module path? You have a file declaring your package as a module, and I’m guessing it’s not mentioning that it requires JUnit5 *there*.

Comment: @nitind Thank you. I was not sure what is module path and I've looked up. And ended up solving this problem by making new package for my test. I would post answer for myself later !

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I don't understand much why. My guess is it goes along with that new module-info thingy. Now I don't know what would be the proper way of using that.
I did what you propose bellow. Does not change a thing. It seems like JUnit is not recognized though it is part of the class path (not module path).
Can you give the steps of what you did to solve this?

Comment: @猫IT Are you sure I have followed the setup ? 
https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php

Comment: Yes I have everything setup correctly as per the good old proven way and also as per what is written in the article but it does not work in my case.
I followed the various ideas mentioned here and none fixed the issue.
One evolution I had is by adding requires junit in the module-info.java file. Error symbols got away in package explorer yet the source still behave the same.
I'm pretty certain it has to do with this module-info not properly setup.
I remade my project using Java 8 so no module-info and it works like a charm.
Now I need to make it work on Java 9+ with module-info.
Regards.

Comment: @猫IT Hi, sorry for not able to help you but I have no idea what is the problem you have. I just get started to Java a month ago. 
Well, what I can say for that is Java programmer don't link to require junit in module-info.java as the the post said below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321602/in-eclipse-what-is-the-difference-between-modulepath-and-classpath

Comment: Thank you for your answer anyway. I'm just trying to learn about this modularity thing because it is the future. From now on Java will support/maintain only the 2/3 last versions of Java which means sooner or later we will be forced to deal with it. while I understand the concepts of Jigsaw i don't understand how to use it and no tutorial or ressource I found could help me tough I saw a video about Eclipse that seems to show JUnit used with module-path. I need to find out. Again thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With @nitind help, I could solve the problem.

Because I did not know what is module path and google it.
I ended up reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321602/in-eclipse-what-is-the-difference-between-modulepath-and-classpath) and in that post it says

> There is one special case: If you have a module-info.java in your
>   project and have test code in your project, you usually don't want to
>   mention test dependencies like junit in the module-info.java. There
>   are two solutions for this:
>
> Create a dedicated test module. This has always been the convention
>   for osgi-based projects. Disadvantage is that you can only use public
>   api in your tests
>
> The solution used by maven: Put your test dependencies on the
>   classpath. When compiling test code, maven adds command line options
>   that allow the code in the named module to read the unnamed module
>   (which is not possible via the module-info.java).

So, as it says I made dedicated test module like the picture below.

[image]

1. Right click the test module
2. Go `Build Path > Configure Build Path`
3. Then toggle `Contains test sources: No` to Yes
4. Check `Allow output folders for source folders`
5. Change the Output Folder to `test` (or anywhere you want other than you default (bin))

[image]

Run the test and the test should work from now.

Comment: Did that. Does not help.