# Is it possible to use external lib with classpath in NetBeans IDE with modular application?

Tags: java, java-module, netbeans-11

In NetBeans 11.0 I created Modular project, which uses external modules and libraries.  If I copy all external modules and libraries on module path, application works fine, but if I set module path for modules and add regular libraries on Classpath, my application isn't able to use them.

Is this mean that I need to put all my external libraries (no matter if they are modules or standard libraries) on module path?

Comment: Yes.  A modular application’s runtime does not look at the classpath.

Comment: @VGR Thank you. If you want, write full answer, so I could mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  A modular application’s runtime effectively ignores the classpath.  This is because the everything in the classpath belongs to the *unnamed module,* which named modules cannot access.

This is described in detail by [Is it possible to mix --class-path and --module-path in javac (JDK 9)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288170/is-it-possible-to-mix-class-path-and-module-path-in-javac-jdk-9).

[In Eclipse, what is the difference between modulepath and classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321602/in-eclipse-what-is-the-difference-between-modulepath-and-classpath) also contains some useful information about this.