# Finding it difficult to add jar files to build path

Tags: java, jar

I am using eclipse 2019, and JDK 13.
I can add jar files. But can't find the option to build path. I tried doing it from properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries too. But Add Jars button seems to be disabled there.

My library screen:
[image: library]

Please help.

Comment: Please add more information. Add eclipse tag, what do you mean by I can add jar file?

Answer (score 1):

> Click on the Modulepath or Classpath to enable the buttons.

**More References:**

[In Eclipse, what is the difference between modulepath and classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321602/in-eclipse-what-is-the-difference-between-modulepath-and-classpath)

[Video explaination - Eclipse Oxygen IDE Improvements: Java 9, JUnit 5, General, Gradle...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&t=80s)